# Keras how to add an attention layer for a weighted sum

Tags: keras, embedding, attention-model

I have the following a network architecture (only the relevant part of the network is shown below)

```
vocab_dimension = 1500
embed_dimension = 10


x = [Input(shape=(None, ), name='input', dtype='int32'),
     Input(shape=(None, ), name='weights'),
     Input(shape=(None, ), name='neg_examples', dtype='int32')]


embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_dimension, output_dim=embed_dimension)


def _weighted_sum(x):
    return K.sum(x[0] * K.expand_dims(x[1], -1), axis=1, keepdims=True)


weighted_sum = Lambda(_weighted_sum, name='weighted_sum')

item_vecs = embedding_layer(x[2])
user_vecs = weighted_sum([embedding_layer(x[0]), x[1]])
```

The problem here is that I would like to not pass the weights as input, but I would like to 'learn' them, like in an attention layer.

I know that attention layers could be created this way

```
attention_probs = Dense(h, activation='softmax', name='attention_probs')(x[0])
weighted_sum = Lambda(_weighted_sum)([x[0], attention_probs])
```

`h` is equal to the dimension of the length of the input, which I set to 5. However, if I do the above I get the following error
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

I think this has to do with the dimensions of the input parameters, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You can't pass an input tensor with unknown shape to a Dense layer.

Comment: Nor you can pass unknown shapes to a weighted sum. (You will end up with exactly the same problem) - Consider using `Input(shape=(someActualLength,))`.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought

Answer (score 0):

If you fix `h` you'll have to fix the length of the input. You put it to be `None` but your dimensions are going to match only in case of `h==input_size`. It strange that you even can pass undefined size to Dense layer usually you'll get error like `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to 'Dense' should be defined. Found 'None'.`

Note that in the Input layer you do not have batch_size. So if your backend tensor should be of size (batch_size,dim1) you create input like `Input((dim1,))`